# Find different elements in two different divs with the same class using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm using Python and Selenium to Scrape a website. Used `find_by_element` to find all the values that I need but I've run into something more challenging. The website html show the exactly structure to two different values and I cannot use a simple `find_element_by_class` because they have the same classes and ids. I don't want to use xpath or selector because I am iterating this through many "flight-row" divs and it would make thinks more hardcoded.

```
<div class="flight-row">
    <div class="row row-eq-heights">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 no-padding"><span class="airline-name">gol</span><span class="flight-number">AM-477</span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="flight-timming"><span class="flight-time">06:15</span><span class="flight-destination">IAH</span></div><span class="flight-data">01/10/19</span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 no-padding">
            <div class="duration"><span class="flight-duration">21:25</span><span class="flight-stops" aria-label="Paradas do voo">2 paradas</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="flight-timming"><span class="flight-destination">GIG</span><span class="flight-time">05:40</span></div><span class="flight-data">02/10/19</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanna get the values from flight-time, flight-destination and flight-data from the both "col-xs-4 col-md-4" divs.

This is a little of my code:

```
outbound_flights = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class^='flight-item ']")

for outbound_flight in outbound_flights:
    airline = outbound_flight.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='airline-name']")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following css selector to get `flight-time`, `flight-destination` and `flight-data`

```
outbound_flights = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.col-xs-4.col-md-4:not(.no-padding)")

for outbound_flight in outbound_flights:
    flight_time = outbound_flight.find_element_by_css_selector("div.flight-timming span.flight-time").text
    print(flight_time)
    flight_destination = outbound_flight.find_element_by_css_selector("div.flight-timming span.flight-destination").text
    print(flight_destination)
    flight_data = outbound_flight.find_element_by_css_selector("span.flight-data").text
    print(flight_data)
```

### Output on console:

```
06:15
IAH
01/10/19
05:40
GIG
02/10/19
```

**EDITED Answer:**

```
outbound_flights = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.col-xs-4.col-md-4:not(.no-padding)")
flighttime=[]
for outbound_flight in outbound_flights:
    flight_time = outbound_flight.find_element_by_css_selector("div.flight-timming span.flight-time").text
    print(flight_time)
    flighttime.append(flight_time)
    flight_destination = outbound_flight.find_element_by_css_selector("div.flight-timming span.flight-destination").text
    print(flight_destination)
    flight_data = outbound_flight.find_element_by_css_selector("span.flight-data").text
    print(flight_data)

departure_time=flighttime[0]
arrival_time=flighttime[1]

print("Departure time :" + departure_time)
print("Arrival time :" + arrival_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've implemented that, but how can I assign a variable to the flight_time number two of this iteration? In this case I would want to get the "05:40" value.

Comment: I've tried var = flight_time[1] and var = flight_time(1). It doesn't works =(

Comment: Why don’t you try the code I have posted.based on your html it is giving me the out you had want.

Comment: I am using the code that you provided me. But I need the first flight_time and the second flight_time assigned in different variables. Example:
departure_time = 06:15
arrival_time = 05:40

Comment: @UalasRohrer : check the edited answer.Hope this is what you are looking after.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get values by index.

`(//*[@class='flight-time'])[1]` and `(//*[@class='flight-time'])[2]`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But this index is an absolute number to all the class='flight-time' of the page. I'm iterating many rows, each one with two class='flight-time' and I wanna be able to get the first and second index of the current iteration.